# How to get right result of ToString() method in enum with two equal items

Tags: c#, enums

I have enum

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
   Item1 = 32768,
   Item2 = 65536,
   Item3 = 524288,
   Item4 = Item3
}
```

Results of ToString() operation:

```
MyEnum.Item3.ToString() - "Item4"
MyEnum.Item4.ToString() - "Item4"
```

Is it possible to get:

```
MyEnum.Item3.ToString() - "Item3"
MyEnum.Item4.ToString() - "Item4"
```

?

Comment: Why do you need two enums with the same value?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't.

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.

[`Enum.ToString()` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No, because you set `Item4` to be equal to `Item3`, and as they're just typesafe ints (enums are), the CLR can't tell the difference.

Try setting `Item4` to a different value to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

No, because `enum` aren't collections of strings. They are value types that can contain an integral of a certain type (normally an `int`), where some of these integrals are connected to a "name" (your Item4)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't understand why you need two items with the same value. However, if you need the same enum values but want the different names later, perhaps try using the `DescriptionAttribute` in `System.ComponentModel`?

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
   [DescriptionAttribute("Item1")]Item1 = 32768,
   [DescriptionAttribute("Item2")]Item2 = 65536,
   [DescriptionAttribute("Item3")]Item3 = 524288,
   [DescriptionAttribute("Item4")]Item4 = Item3
}
```

Then you could this method to get the description value back:

```
public string ValueOf(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[]) fi.GetCustomAttributes( typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    if (attributes.Length > 0)
    {
        return attributes[0].Description;
    }
    else
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I've not actually tried this out, so the MSDN quote @MarcinJuraszek posted might still apply here.

Source: http://blog.waynehartman.com/articles/84.aspx